# create a calendar of any year in ms word file using java

Tags: java, file, apache-poi, xwpf

I am trying to create calendar of any year in ms word file using java.could you please help me out.thanks in advance.

Comment: Do your own homework.

Comment: Check out the Apache POI library for creating word docs [link](http://poi.apache.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Following is the code to write calender for particular year in docx file

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTable;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTableRow;

public class MyCalendar {

    //Blank Document
      static XWPFDocument document= new XWPFDocument();

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        // represents the year
        int year;

        // ask year from user
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter year: ");

        // read them as string
        String yearText = in.next();

        in.close();

        try {


               //Write the Document in file system
               FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("Year "+yearText+".docx"));

            // throws NumberFormatException if not convertible.
            // It would be caught below:
            year = Integer.parseInt(yearText);

            // print the calendar for the given year.
            for(int i=1; i<=12; i++){
                printCalendarMonthYear(i, year);
            }

            document.write(out);
            out.close();

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // handles NumberFormatException
            System.err.println("Numberat Error: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // handles any other Exception
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /*
     * prints a calendar month based on month / year info
     */
    private static void printCalendarMonthYear(int month, int year) {
        // create a new GregorianCalendar object
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();

        // set its date to the first day of the month/year given by user
        cal.clear();
        cal.set(year, month - 1, 1);

        document.createParagraph().createRun().setText(""+cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG,
                        Locale.US) + " " + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));

        // obtain the weekday of the first day of month.
        int firstWeekdayOfMonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        // obtain the number of days in month.
        int numberOfMonthDays = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // print anonymous calendar month based on the weekday of the first
        // day of the month and the number of days in month:
        printCalendar(numberOfMonthDays, firstWeekdayOfMonth-1);
    }

    /*
     *  prints an anonymous calendar month based on the weekday of the first
     *  day of the month and the number of days in month:
     */
    private static void printCalendar(int numberOfMonthDays, int firstWeekdayOfMonth) {

        // reset index of weekday
        int weekdayIndex = 0;

        // print calendar weekday header
        XWPFTable table = document.createTable();
        //create first row
        XWPFTableRow tableRowOne = table.getRow(0);
        tableRowOne.getCell(0).setText("Su");
        tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("Mo");
        tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("Tu");
        tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("We");
        tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("Th");
        tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("Fr");
        tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("Sa");

        // leave/skip weekdays before the first day of month
        XWPFTableRow tableRow = table.createRow();
        int ind = 0;
        for (int day = 1; day <= firstWeekdayOfMonth; day++) {
            ind = day;
            tableRow.getCell(ind).setText(" ");
            weekdayIndex++;
        }

        // print the days of month in tabular format.
        for (int day = 1; day <= numberOfMonthDays; day++) {
            // print day

            tableRow.getCell(ind).setText(""+day);

            // next weekday
            weekdayIndex++;
            // if it is the last weekday
            if (weekdayIndex == 7) {
                // reset it
                weekdayIndex = 0;
                // and go to next line

                tableRow = table.createRow();
                ind = 0;
            }
            else { // otherwise
                // print space
                ind++;
            }
        }

        // print a final new-line.
        document.createParagraph().createRun().addBreak();
    }
}
```

This will create docx file with year name

You will need following jar files to run this code

poi-3.11.jar

poi-ooxml-3.11.jar

poi-ooxml-schemas-3.11.jar

xmlbeans-2.6.jar

Comment: Thanks @Atish Bundhe. That i know and even i had done it as You have done this. The problem that i am facing in padding the value in table.I am able to create table but not able to pad value in each cell. Could you can help me out in this way.

Comment: I have edited my answer as per your need. Try it